# Правильно ли я поставила знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Белая сторона для магнитов и для рисования маркерами на водной основе, черная для рисования мелом.

Comment: Я бы ещё поставил два тире, одно - после "сторона", второе -  после "чёрная".

Answer (score 1):

Белая сторона – для магнитов и для рисования маркерами на водной основе, черная – для рисования мелом.

После *белая сторона* лучше поставить тире (подразумевается, *что белая сторона предназначена* для...), после *черная* тоже нужно поставить тире.